# Enrichment of GO terms of a set of genes using TopGO

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am trying to derive a list of enriched GO terms from a set of genes given by a user. The way I understand and am implementing is:

My input is a csv file consisting of about 500 genes.

```
>library(topGO)        
>library(hgu133plus2.db)
>all.genes <- ls(hgu133plus2ACCNUM) # I guess, this creates my gene universe

>data <- read.csv(file.choose(),header=FALSE) #Here I give an input csv file containing     genes

>relevant.genes <- factor(as.integer(all.genes %in% data)
>names(relevant.genes) <- all.genes
>GOdata.BP <- new("topGOdata", ontology='BP', allGenes = relevant.genes, annotationFun =annFUN.db, affyLib = 'hgu133plus2.db')
```

I get the following error after this:

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : allGenes must be a factor with 2 levels
> str(relevant.genes)
Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:54675] "1007_s_at" "1053_at" "117_at" "121_at" ...
```

Can you please direct me where am I going wrong? Am I right in using TopGO for this, even though I dont have expression values.

Comment: I ran your code, except that I used another db (ath1121501.db) and it works. So, I suspect that your problem is related to `data` because I actually use `data <- all.genes[500:1000]` and get it work.

Comment: My data is in a CSV file with 1 column of values. Values here are gene symbols. Should I restructure my data in CSV in a different style?

Also, what does `data <- all.genes[500:!000]` accomplish here?

Comment: @Benny Like ptocquin said, the problem is with `data`. Basically `all.genes %in% data` is returning only `FALSE`. I might be able to help you figure out why if you add the output of `dput(data)` to your question. Also, `data <- all.genes[500:1000]` is just a quick way of picking ~500 genes, which is what you said your CSV file contains.